# How do I make invisible files (like bash profile) visible in the finder?

Tags: macbook-pro, bash

question is in the title. There's some files that most Apple users don't need access to, but if you program you do need access to. in particular the bash profile. anyone know how to make these visible in the finder?

i'm using a macbook pro 10.6.8

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is set the `AppleShowAllFiles` preference to "true." From terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true
```

If you'd like to reverse the change, enter the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles false
```

For the changes to take effect, either restart the Finder or logout and back in.

Comment: To see the changes you may have to restart the Finder.

Comment: And set it to 0 if you want to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten very attached to an utility which makes toggling "see invisible files" trivial; I highly recommend it to anyone else.

TotalFinder: http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/.  At time of writing, the author is asking $18, but he also gives away free license (for a number of reasons).

Comment: Why down-vote this?  The utility has saved me a lot of time switching the setting back and forth.  The answer was written with the intention of being helpful to others; there is nothing spiteful, malicious, or misleading.

Comment: +1 for TotalFinder because it also doesn't require relaunching the Finder. I suggested TotalFinder in a [similar question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26886/can-you-hide-hidden-files-in-specific-folders-like-the-desktop-while-keeping-t/26896#26896) and it was down-voted without explanation, too. It makes no sense to me for someone to down-vote a viable answer without explanation. If there's a good reason for the down-vote, it remains unknown and the answer will likely be repeated elsewhere.