# Hide globally specific files

Tags: finder, macos

I ran in the terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

and I wonder how to hide some files like: **.localized** and **DS_Store** as they are messing around on desktop and other directories. Is there any way to do so? or at least do not show hidden files on specific directory

Comment: Here is a very similar question and answers:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26886/can-you-hide-hidden-files-in-specific-folders-like-the-desktop-while-keeping-t

Comment: You might want to consider the opposite way. Only unhide the files you want to see, not all system files.

Comment: @viperking you do understand what those files are and do right?

Comment: I wasn't concerned much about them, is there anything I should know?

Comment: Messing around with system files? There is a very reason they are hidden. Use Open then press (cmd+shift+.)