# Can't access /etc folder in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, folders

In OS X Mountain Lion's Finder, I can see a grayed-out `/etc` folder, but cannot see inside.  Using Terminal's `ls` command, I can see the existence of a file that one of my programs is trying to find (Free Pascal's `fpc` program has a `fpc.cfg` file in `/etc`).

How can I change parameters for this folder to enable more open access?

Answer (score 10):

Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (or select `Go` - `Go to Folder...` from the Finder menu bar) and enter `/etc` or any existing and readable path as the target location to browse it.

Given you enabled [showing of hidden files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24855/how-do-i-make-invisible-files-like-bash-profile-visible-in-the-finder#24856), while double-clicking `etc` from Finder does not work, you can still right-click it and choose `Open` from the context menu.

The system-wide configuration files in `/etc` are best to be treated with caution just as all the other hidden system files and therefor I'd certainly not recommend changing permissions for them, but if you do need to view or edit them I would suggest doing it from the Terminal. This will also make it easier to gain the necessary root privileges for changing them by using the `sudo` command.

Answer (score -2):

```
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel       11 Oct 19 16:00 etc -> private/etc
```

the folder owner is root. if your program need to access it, you can run it under root account.

Comment: Read access is enabled for all users (that's what the `rwxr-xr-x` at the beginning says)

Comment: OT doesn't say what kind of access he need. I do know r-x allows read and execute access.

Comment: Fair point. But enabling the root account just to edit a file in `/etc` seems a bit too much. It's easier to use `sudo` for this.