# How do I edit bash shell terminal history?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, history

I entered a password in a command line pro or in a terminal window by mistake and do not want to remove my whole history. My shell is bash.

How do I edit my bash history in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 18):

Editing the `.bash_history` is just a matter of opening the file with an editor. There are a couple of ways you could achieve this.

1. In the **Terminal** just type `vi ~/.bash_history`, then edit the file as you want, and save. This option could be tricky, if you're not used to *vi*, of course.
2. Make the file *visible* by following [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24856/21487) instructions, for instance, open it as any other file, modify it, and save.
3. In the **Terminal** just type `open -e ~/.bash_history`. This command will open the file with **TextEdit**, you can choose any other text editor, of course. Modify the file and save.

For the changes to be noticeable just restart the bash.

Comment: I think I found my answer. `echo $HISTFILE` shows the one to edit.

Comment: @VictorEngel That was helpful; thanks. For me, it was `open -e ~/.zsh_history`.

Answer (score 13):

In terminal type `history` and note the line number. Next call `history -d noted-line-number`. You can check that the line is deleted using `history` again.

Comment: This does not work on Yosemite with ZSH.

Comment: The question was about bash, not zsh. Read carefully!

Comment: @DmitryDupelov you are right, sorry to bother. 
Anyway, it's a reminder to future readers (that may miss that detail as well). Thank you for correcting my comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
nano ~/.bash_history
```

when you done, 
`ctrl+x`
and come back to accept a right answer dude

Answer (score 1):

I think that Dmitry's answer is ideal if done before *saving* the history - by default, saving occurs on shell/terminal exit.

If you may have already *saved* the history to ~/.bash_history, then I prefer Thecafremo's answer, but I would suggest adding a step of exiting Terminal to ensure that none of the bash instances have loaded the history and will re-save it.  This is especially tricky if you have multiple terminals and have enabled any sort of command-by-command history update.

Background:

- bash saves the history within an instance of the shell
- bash can write this history to a file, which typically happens when you exit the shell/Terminal
- bash can read from a file into the history, which typically happens when you open a shell/Terminal
- it's possible to change the default behavior so that history propagates sooner, which can migrate your BAD_TEXT to the file and to other windows

Regardless of which method you use, I would add one step: verify success!

1. Exit Terminal.app
2. Re-open Terminal.app
3. Confirm the offending text is not in the history - preferably in a way that will not create additional history.  That is, don't `grep BAD_TEXT .bash_history`!  This new command would go into history.  I'd just open .bash_history in your favorite editor and search within that for BAD_TEXT.

This should give you peace of mind that you have eliminated BAD_TEXT no matter what kind of crazy bash setup you may encounter.

Answer (score 1):

There are several histories for example bash and zsh. You can do this with nano. To do this, simply open the terminal

With this you edit the bash history

```
nano $HOME/.bash_history
```

With this you edit the standard zsh history

```
nano $HOME/.zsh_history
```

If you want, you can do the whole thing using TextEdit.

Bash:  `open -t $HOME/.bash_history`

Zsh:   `open -t $HOME/.zsh_history`

Comment: Let’s get this in a question asking for zsh history for best effect.