# Restore open Terminal sessions from Time Machine backup?

Tags: terminal, time-machine

I just did a Time Machine restore of the full system on Catalina, and seems to have worked pretty well, with one exception - I had several Terminal windows open with bash history, but these haven't been restored this time.

Where are these past terminal sessions stored?  Could there be a way for me to restore these files specifically from some past Time Machine backup?

I did this once before with Chrome when it lost open windows and tabs; Chrome is a little temperamental when restoring open windows and tabs; in this case it restored some but not all; then, close the app and reopen it and all the original tabs appeared. Not so with Terminal, though (I closed and reopened the app and the lost windows don't appear).

Wondering if anyone knows which files I could look for on a Time Machine backup and try restoring those specific files manually to get the sessions back.

### Update

I have the following in `~/.bash_sessions`

```
mbp:~ m$ ls -lat ~/.bash_sessions/*.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 12:14 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/6719BAE0-CEC7-4629-B1D6-0A11D0E79409.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 10:12 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/33C3A9A3-0179-45BC-996F-9FC540BC3F91.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 09:52 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/BEB93945-EECB-495C-85CF-BA6DD8E26DF0.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 09:39 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/3D845B8E-6924-4E60-B941-8E00DF6136CA.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 09:38 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/03774130-209A-4420-9EE5-3D7E03A70824.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 09:31 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/78EF93CA-705B-41D0-A2E7-00AE41C37BF5.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 23 Jun 09:31 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/8E7F0142-4F7A-49B3-88BF-51B404696392.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52  3 Jun 09:54 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/9D750CAA-397F-4E84-9EB1-AB7991BF4A84.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 31 May 19:20 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/0BF6D4CF-53AA-4BC9-8CAE-44C6C29531CA.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 31 May 18:32 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/12A8BB4A-828B-4936-9D83-F3CD95D3A142.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 31 May 18:19 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/F91389BC-C1F3-477C-94D9-A9535C7AB2FA.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 31 May 18:09 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/5B877A51-A4C3-4420-AD63-BA55CF19513E.session

...clipped more than 100 lines ...

-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 20 Feb 10:57 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/E7F75EDA-9EA3-406C-99BA-281B1CFFFCC1.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 19 Feb 16:04 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/0B620390-0137-46FB-B3E9-C77F50A677E2.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 19 Feb 16:03 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/F645F431-BF46-4406-81B3-8925324CE76D.session
-rw-------  1 m  staff  52 18 Feb 09:37 /Users/m/.bash_sessions/1422B462-17ED-49D7-9481-AB54A812D47B.session
mbp:~ m$
```

Comment: Did you restore from a Catalina backup or did you restore a Mojave system into a Catalina installation?

Comment: From a Catalina backup - a backup of only a day previously.

Comment: This might help - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87888/how-do-i-edit-mac-os-x-terminal-history

Comment: Several other apps managed to restore their open windows correctly - sublime text, sublime merge, textedit; but *on this occasion*, only terminal didn't.

Comment: There are no recent bash sessions in that list, so I assume Terminal was still open while the backup was running?

Comment: @nohillside Above now shows recent bash sessions (via `ls -t`). maybe clipped last time, as so many entries.

Comment: These most recent ones all seem to just contain one line with something like `echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r 1590945542)"
` though, loosing the history. i'm going to take a look what's in this dir in a tm backup.

Comment: All of the session files are like this, the shell history is in the .history files. And the open tabs as such are in a Terminal preference somewhere (.bash_sessions is just the content)

Comment: @nohillside Can you give any more clues on "a Terminal preference somewhere"? :)

Comment: `~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState/`

Comment: I used finder to `go` to that folder then went into time machine, but that directory seems unavailable on backup disk; it's captured on local snapshots though, but they're all after the restore, of course. Strange that local snapshots record that dir, but tm drives seem not to.

Comment: Is there a way to read `.data` & `.plist`?

Comment: `man plutil`. But if they are not on the backup they are gone.

Comment: I just checked in my TM backups: `Saved Application State` doesn't seem to get backuped by TM.

Comment: ok - i wondered if since if (some of) the data is in `.bash_sessions`, if I could read the .plist and .data files i could fake (create) one to point to the apropriate files in `.bash_sessions`