# How to delete the terminal history in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, zsh, history

I'm trying to delete the terminal history but the .zsh_history does not allow me to run it, it says permission denied. Please help.

Comment: Fixed https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418231 . You can also try `sudo chown -R $(stat -f %Su) ~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At System Preferences/Security and Privacy/Privacy unlock the padlock and add the terminal to "Full disk access". Then reload the terminal and retry.
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/mac

Comment: Yeah! This helped, thank you! But the actual command was: rm ~/.zsh_history

Answer (score 2):

Run it?  Why would you run it?  It's a file in your `$HOME`.  Delete it, if that's what you've set `HISTFILE` to for the shell to keep the history in.